# Spring Sqlite in memory database broken?

Tags: java, spring, sqlite, jdbc, in-memory-database

I tried unit test my database code with an in-memory database but somehow this does not work:

I prepared a snippet to show this:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        //When this variable is set to a filename
        //like "test.db" everything works
        String file = ":memory:";

        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
        SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource(config);
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + file);
        JdbcTemplate temp = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        temp.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
        temp.update("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1), (2)");
        temp.query("SELECT * FROM test", (rs, rowNum) -> {
            System.out.println(rs);
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

This code throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1), (2)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; no such table: test; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: no such table: test
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:415)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:534)
  at ch.tiim.sco.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:19)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: no such table: test
  at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:397)
  at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
  at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:523)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:520)
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
... 7 more
```

But only when the database is set to in memory mode.
Is this a bug in spring? It can't be a bug in SQLite or in the xerial SQLite driver because when I use JDBC directly everything works.

Every pointer and hint is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:
Actually the exact same thing happens with the h2 database too.
So it must be a problem on how my end or with spring.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently closes SQLite and H2 the database as soon as the last connection closes. In H2 this can be fixed with `jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`